# Use html include in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, html, spring

Can I insert some includes in a spring mvc controller to point to various html files to assemble them as one page, kind of like (for example):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = QUESTION_GROUP_CREATE_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
String createQuestionGroup(@RequestBody JsonQuestionGroup questionGroup, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return "<div></div>";
}
```

but where I'm returning `"<div></div>"` can I use includes to link to head.html, header.html, nav.html, view.html, footer.html? Example?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use apach tiles instead of that ,It is very easy

Comment: Why are you not using `jsp` for this?

Comment: I can't use jsp, only *.html, and I have severe browser limitations - the controller seems to be the most comfortable place to assemble it..

Comment: So you basically want to use your Spring Controller as a Java Servlet before the times of JSP was introduced. I can only strongly suggest against it. You should use some form of templating (jsp, velocity, freemarker or something similar), or your code will be an unmaintanable mess sooner or later. If you really want to do this, then read the html files as simple files, then concatenate their contents as strings.

Answer (score -1):

You can use apache tiles instead of that ,It is very easy You can find many tutorial in web this is an example
http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-mvc-and-apache-tiles-integration-example/

another one
https://bikashshaw.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/spring-mvc-create-jspjstl-composite-view-header-body-and-footer/

Comment: This is not an answer, with examples it could be however.

Comment: Posting links in itself, is still not a very useful way to provide answers in Stack Overflow, as links are not very future proof.